# PHP conflict with do-while end mysql_fetch_array?

Tags: php

here's my code, there's something wrong, because when I put this in wamp (chrome), it returns me a duplicate "published by" (for any doubts, $conex = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root') )

```
      <?php
  mysql_select_db("spectrum-solaris",$conex);
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT id,name,tittle,body FROM articles ORDER BY id          DESC",$conex);
  $row = mysql_num_rows($query);
  if($row > 0 ){
  do {
?>
    <div class ="tematica" >
    <p>
        <small>Published by <b><a href="user.php"><?= $row['name'] ?></a></b></small>
    </p>
        <p>
            <big><a href="show.php"><?= $row['tittle'] ?></a></big>
        </p>
        <p>
            <b><?=$row['body']?></b>
        </p>        
    </div>
<?php
    }while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query));
}
    mysql_free_result($query);

    mysql_close($conex);
```

this is the result (the blue lines are made by me on PAINT):

(http://spectrum-solaris.meximas.com/stack2.PNG)

Comment: Think about it: what is `$row` on the first iteration and what is it on the second iteration? In fact, activate error reporting to get a hint.

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions are **no longer maintained** and shouldn't be used in any new codebase. It is being phased out in favor of newer APIs. Instead you should use [**prepared statements**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY) with either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli).

Answer (score 1):

`do { } while()` is not appropriate for a DB loop. On your FIRST past through the `do`. $row isn't going to be a DB result. It's going to be a simple integer - the number of rows in the result.

You want this instead:

```
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Saw this some time ago: `$row = fetch_array(); if ($row != FALSE) { do { ... } while ($row = fetch_array()); }` - would this be considered bad practice? Thought it was quite good to check if there had been returned any rows at all

Comment: if you fetched a row first, it'd be fine. but you're not, you're fetching a row count into the same variable you use for your rows.

Comment: @king Unless you're also doing an `else` that's just needlessly repetitive, nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

You don't fetch a row of your resultset on the first iteration... so `$row` doesn't contain datas on this first iteration.

You could try something like :

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){ // or mysql_fetch_array or ...
    // ...
}
```

If you really want to use `do{}while` despite it's unsuitable for your use :

```
do {
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query); // or mysql_fetch_array or ...
    // ...
} while ($row);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this, instead of `do { } while()`

```
if($row > 0 ){  

    while($rowData = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
?>
        <div class ="tematica" >
        <p>
        <small>Published by <b><a href="user.php"><?= $rowData['name'] ?></a></b></small>
        </p>
        <p>
            <big><a href="show.php"><?= $rowData['tittle'] ?></a></big>
        </p>
        <p>
            <b><?=$rowData['body']?></b>
        </p>        
        </div>
<?php
      }
}
mysql_free_result($query);

mysql_close($conex);
```